# Sending AT command to esp8266 using stm32F103 through usart

Tags: c, esp8266, at-command, keil, stm32f1

i'm trying to communicate with a Wifi module (esp8266) using STM32F103, on keil IDE.
As described in the schematic :
i want making my stm32  send AT command to esp8266 through usart1 (Tx1), and getting the esp response (Rx1), then display the esp response on computer serial monitor using usart2 ( Tx2).

After configuring usart1 and usart2, and writing the functions to send an receive data, i'm getting only the ECHO of the command, rather than the response which should be "OK"`enter code here` .
when i'm sending "AT\r\n", i'm receiving only AT on serial monitor.
i will share the code i have wrote, and the traces on logic analyzer.
if there is any suggestion i will be thankful.

```
 int len=0;
char buff[256];

int main(void){
    
     __disable_irq();
    
    
    systick_init();
  UART1_Init();
    UART2_Init();

  Delayms(100);
    
printMsg1("AT\r\n");
    
    Delayms(100);
    
    NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
    
    __enable_irq();
    
while(1){}

}


void USART1_IRQHandler(){

if (USART1->SR & USART_SR_RXNE) // if received data (RXNE event flag is set) is ready to be read -->RXNE
            {
    
             buff[len] = USART1->DR;
                            
                Delayms(100);
                
                printMsg2(buff);

    }
                
}

void printMsg1(char *msg, ...)  // Sending AT command to ESP  ( Stm32-> ESP8266)
{

 va_list args;
 va_start(args,msg); 
 vsprintf(buff,msg,args);
 
 for(int i=0;i<strlen(buff);i++)
 {


   USART1->DR = (buff[i]&0xFF);
     while(!(USART1->SR & USART_SR_TXE)); //wait for TXE, 1 = data transferred
   
  }
}

void printMsg2(char *msg, ...)  // Sending ESP response to Serial Monitor ( STM32-> PC)
{

 va_list args;
 va_start(args,msg); 
 vsprintf(buff,msg,args);
 
 for(int i=0;i<strlen(buff);i++)
 {
   USART2->DR = buff[i];
   while(!(USART2->SR & USART_SR_TXE)); //wait for TXE, 1 = data transferred
  }
}
```

[Serial monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w7KH.png)

[Logic Analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zF5cG.png)

[Pseudo-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40nAy.jpg)

Comment: What if you send only `AT\r`, instead? I mean, without the trailing `\n`

Comment: i'm getting AT\r, it seems that the stm32 is echoing what i'm sending !!

Comment: Oh, I see. You use the same `buff` to place data received from the usart1, that's why you just print what you tried to send to the modem. Furthermore you should increment `len` each time you get a character in your isr, and send back len characters (vsnprintf requires null terminated strings)

Comment: well suggested ! i will adapt my code and see what's happen.
Thank you

Comment: You're right ! it works now .
 the same buffer is used for sending the AT command and receiving the response  "buff[len]", 
which place the receiving data also in buff[len] and seems to be ignored, 
this is why i'm receiving the command echo.
Furthemore it turns out that the "Delayms" function  corrupted or caused the losses of the received data ,  perhaps this is due to the fact that the long waiting time leads to the loss of data.
Thank you !!